# Promise.all with dependency of first promise response on second promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to use Promise.all of which, second promise is dependent on first promise response.
Here is my code

```
let user = await userService.getByKey({ _id: params.userId });
let room = await matchService.findUserInRoom(user._id);
let match = await matchService.findMatch(params.userId);
```

But what now I was trying is to do it using Promise.all. Something like

```
let [user, room, match ] = await Promise.all([firstPromise, secondPromise, thirdPromise])
```

And I just don't know how to do it this way, tried a lot to find some reference but unable to. As because my second promise is dependent on the response of first promise just stuck how to pass this way

Comment: If the promises are dependant on each other, then you cannot use `Promise.all` - that's for independent promises. You need to use the regular promise API (or `async`/`await`) in order to sequence the related promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call the first and second asynchronous API calls concurrently, but third one is independent so you can do it like the following:

```
async function getRoom(params) {
   const user = await userService.getByKey({ _id: params.userId });
   const room = await matchService.findUserInRoom(user._id);
   return [user, room];
}

const [[user, room], match] =  await Promise.all([
   getRoom(params),
   matchService.findMatch(params.userId)
]);
```

Comment: Thanks @polyglot this is better than what I have tried. Accepted